# Segregate elements of a string output

Tags: c#, odata

My C# output is in the form:

```
Epoch Timestamp1,Cost1,Epoch Timestamp2,Cost2,Epoch Timestamp3,Cost3.
```

(Costn is the cost for Epoch TImestampn.)

I want to get the cost for each timestamp, in the below manner:

```
timestamp cost
timestamp cost
..
..
..
```

I am implementing this in C# in Visual Studio 2017.
How can I implement this? Any ideas please?

Thank you.

Comment: You can do this by writing code.

Comment: I meant.. what methods/functions can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Split` and a `for` loop, add pepper and salt to taste

```
var input = "Epoch Timestamp1,Cost1,Epoch Timestamp2,Cost2,Epoch Timestamp3,Cost3.";

var split = input.Split(',');
var results = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i+=2)
   results.Add(split[i] + " " + split[i + 1]);

foreach (var item in results)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

[See it in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ghnwVv)

Comment: Worked wonderfully. Thank you so much Michael. :)